# populate combobox from another workbook

Tags: excel, vba

How can I populate a combobox from another workbook, assuming that my data are in a worksheet named "affectation" and the data are in the 1st column
[image]
My combobox is in a userform, to fill it from the activeworkbook I use this code :

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ws_Liste_affect As Worksheet
Set ws_Liste_affect = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("affectation")
Fin_Liste_affect = ws_Liste_affect.Range("A65530").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To Fin_Liste_affect
    UserForm1.ComboBox_affect.AddItem ws_Liste_affect.Range("A" & i)

Next

UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

I wan to fill it from another workbook.

Comment: Please provide some more details, it's really hard to understand the meaning of "combobox from another workbook" - a workbook is an Excel file, and a combobox is a COM object, it's hard to understand the correlation between the two without a visual/detailed description

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, is your combobox on your worksheet or in a form? If it's on a sheet, what type of combobox is it?

Comment: @MeirGabay I edited my question, take a look thank u.

Comment: @Zac I edited my question please take a look.

Comment: Is your combo box in another workbook, or you need populating a combo box with data from another workbook?

Comment: @FaruSZ still not 100% sure I understand the question but I'll try my best. You're using `ActiveWorkbook` which is your current workbook, you mentioned that you want to read from **another** workbook, so you need to fetch that workbook, either by index or name, see here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.workbooks#example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I (only) suppose that you need to populate a combo box **using data from a sheet of another workbook**. If my understanding is correct, please try the next code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click__()
 Dim ws_Liste_affect As Worksheet, Fin_Liste_affect As Long, arr As Variant
 Dim wbFullPath As String, wb As Workbook, boolFound As Boolean
 
 wbFullPath = "C:\...\TheOtherWorkbook.xls"
 For Each wb In Workbooks
    If wb.FullName = wbfullname Then
        Set ws_Liste_affect = wb.Worksheets("the other sheet")
        boolFound = True: Exit For
    End If
 Next
 If Not boolFound Then
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(vbfullpath)
    Set ws_Liste_affect = wb.Worksheets("the other sheet")
 End If
 
 Fin_Liste_affect = ws_Liste_affect.Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

 arr = ws_liste.affect.Range("A2:A" & Fin_Liste_affect).Value
 UserForm1.ComboBox_affect.List = arr

 UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Might be worth checking if the **the other workbook** is open. If not then you might want to open it. Also,I would set this code in `UserForm_Initialize` so that `ComboBox` is updated when the form is opened

Comment: @Zac: You can make a lot of improvements, but I only tried answering his question, even if for doing that I had to make an assumption... About the `UserForm_Initialize` or a button solution it is difficult to be sure what he really needs. He maybe needs to press this button to populate it with what he says now and another button to clear the combo and populate it with data from another source...

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions. If you are having a problem, please ask a new question and include a [mcve].